# limits of definite integral for which definite integral is minimum

Tags: calculus

> If $\displaystyle f(x)=\int^{b}_{a}(x^4-2x^2)dx$ is minimum.
>
> Then values  of $a$ and $b$ are

Try: I have partial derivative

$$ \frac{df}{db}=b^4-2b^2$$

And $$\frac{df}{da}=a^4-2a^2$$

For maximum and minimum $\displaystyle \frac{df}{da}=0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{df}{db}=0$

So $a^4-2a^2=0\Rightarrow a=0,\pm \sqrt{2}.$

and $b^4-2b^2=0\Rightarrow b=0,\pm\sqrt{2}.$

So we have $(a,b)=\bigg\{(0,0),\bigg(-\sqrt{2},0\bigg),\bigg(0,\sqrt{2}\bigg)\bigg\}$

But answer given as $(a,b)=\bigg(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\bigg)$

Could some help me How interval is $\bigg(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\bigg)$

thanks in advance

Comment: You can also proceed by showing that $x^4-2x^2\leq 0$ only on that interval.

Comment: $\frac{df}{da}=2a^2-a^4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any optimization problem, the critical points give you a list of possibilities. (Actually, endpoints of $\pm\infty$ should be in there as well - they're the supremum, as those integrals diverge to $\infty$.)

It's still only a list of possibilities. Among the intervals with both endpoints in $\{-\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2}\}$ - six possibilities - we still have to find which one produces the smallest (most negative) integral. As it turns out, it's $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, the largest of those possible intervals.

Oh, and we do need the assumption that $a\le b$ here. Without it, $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} x^4-2x^2\,dx=-\infty$ overwhelms what we're looking for.